# Private helm repository failed to download chart

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I have created a private repository in Azure following this example: https://jessicadeen.com/how-to-create-a-public-helm-repo-using-azure-storage/. Everything worked fine, I was able to push my chart, add repository to my cluster and even to deploy it. In the next day I tried to upgrade my newly pushed chart which unfortunately isn't working anymore, it complains always with the generic error: `Error: failed to download "azikiel/calendar" (hint: running "helm repo update" may help)`
which is weird because I can see my new version of chart added to the cluster after repo update:

```
❯  helm search repo calendar
NAME                    CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
azikiel/calendar        0.2.1           1.16.0          A Helm chart for Kubernetes
```

I remember that in the first time while deploying first version of my chart I haven't set up a SaS token or any other authentication method to pull it. Although I suspect that there was involved an environment variable which is missing in my new terminal session.

Please guide me on what is wrong in my setup.

Comment: any useful info with `--debug ` option?

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was in the script that I created to push to Azure - it was corrupted. It was pushing `index.yaml` file so my repo new about new versions of my chart, but it was failing to push the chart itself to remote.
As per Vitalii's suggestion I was able to see that helm simply could not find that version of chart.